# Least action principle remark on negative mass in Landau-Lifshitz classical mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, mass, variational-principle, action

In the famous Landau-Lifshitz's Classical Mechanics there is a remark I cannot fully understand at the very beginning of the book (page 7 of the second edition):

> It is easy to see that mass of a particle cannot be negative. For, according to the principle of least action, the integral
> \begin{equation}
> S = \int_1^2 \frac{1}{2}mv^2 dt
> \end{equation}
> has a minimum for the actual motion of the particle in space from point 1 to point 2. If the mass were negative, the action integral would take arbitrarily large negative values for a motion in which the particle rapidly left the point 1 and rapidly approached point 2, and there would be no minimum.

Can someone explain me why a change in sign of mass implies the integral to take "arbitrarily large negative values"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the following. When we write $S=\int dt\frac{1}{2}m v^2$ what we really mean is $S=S[x]$. That is, $S$ is a functional of the path $x(t)$ we choose to evaluate it on (and $v=\frac{d x}{d t}$). That means we get to *choose* what function $x(t)$ we evaluate $S$ on. The entire purpose of action minimization is to find the $x(t)$ such that $S$ takes its minimal value. If $m$ is negative, then $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is negative and can be made arbitrarily negative by simply selecting functions $x(t)$ with larger and larger first derivatives (make $v$ larger).

This is the argument that Landau and Lifshitz are shooting at. In reality, however, the Euler-Lagrange equations we derive only ensure we are at a local extrema in the space of paths $x(t)$. This is equivalent to the statement that the vanishing of a function's derivative can only tell you that you're at an extrema, not whether it's a minima or maxima. So typically, the solution to the equations of motion will only be a saddle point of the action, not necessarily a minima.

In so far as I'm aware, there's not actually a good classical reason why we should demand the equations of motion form a minima. The closest thing I'm aware of would have to do with boundedness of the action for the sake of Feynman path integrations in quantum mechanics, but of course that should have no bearing upon classical physics.

Comment: There are classes of cases such that the true trajectory corresponds to a maximum of Hamilton's action. As you state, the vanishing derivative condition identifies an extremum, regardless of whether it's a minimum or a maximum. A physicist can set up a numerical analysis of a particular case using the Euler-Lagrange equation. The case may be one with a maximum action. But that information doesn't make it to the Euler-Lagrange equation; the numerical analysis proceeds the same either way. So: while interesting, it's never *necessary* to know minimum/maximum.

Comment: @Cleonis yes, that's the point I was making.

Comment: The readon I commented: there is a definitive reason why we should not demand only a minimum of the action corresponds to a true trajectory. There are classes of cases where the true trajectory corresponds to a maximum. Speculation: could it be that this signifies a fundamental distinction between Hamilton's stationary action and action formulation in quantum physics?

Comment: @Cleonis ...right, but again this is what I said restated in different words. If you're looking to ask me about constraints on the action enforced by quantum mechanics, it's an interesting point but really only tangentially related to OP's question here. I suggest that if such a question doesn't already have an answer, you ask it.

Comment: Ok, I got the point about the functional and now I mathematically understand the point. Now I am a bit confused about the fact that, if you don't actually need a minimum for $S$, there is no reason to exclude negative mass following this reasoning. I mean, at this point you could revert the reasoning for path which $\textbf{maximize}$ $S$ and get that you don't need, paradoxally on the physical side, positive mass

Comment: @Ehub yes that's correct. Landau and Lifshitz are making their argument based on the need to minimize the action, but there's no good reason to do so. This is partially endemic of Galilean relativity which does not say anything about the sign of the mass. Special relativity specifies a mass squared, so you can always select the mass itself to be the positive square root of the mass squared.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the reasoning in Landau-Lifshitz is as follows:

There is no limit to the form of the variation. With a negative value for mass $m$ we have the following: The action $S$ evaluates to a negative value, and for any trial trajectory there are beyond that trial trajectory other trial trajectories that evaluate to a *more negative value*. That is, if you take a detour instead of the shortest path, then there is always a way to make an *even longer detour*. But the total duration is a given, so the longer the detour the higher the corresponding velocity to make it to the end point in time. So: the larger the detour the larger the $v^2$ part. Hence: if for mass $m$ a negative value is used then the larger the detour the more negative the action.

However, the reasoning presented in Landau-Lifshitz is fundamentally flawed. Hamilton's stationary action is ill suited to the purpose. Hamilton's stationary action itself is sound, of course, but here it is misused, so in the end you are none the wiser.

As a matter of principle Hamilton's action is about *stationary action*, not "least action". This is not a technical detail, it makes all the difference.

The derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation to find solutions for a variational problem is agnostic as to whether the the extremum solution is a minimum or a maximum.

There are in fact classes of cases where Hamilton's action is a maximum. This is not well know, because - as I said - the Euler-Lagrange equation is agnostic as to whether the extremum is a minimum or a maximum. Whether the action is a minimum or a maximum is immaterial. Therefore any reasoning based on an assumption that there must always be a minimum action is flawed, and you are none the wiser.

Comment: I kinda agree with your point of view. In fact, I was suspicious about the fact that there must be a minimum at all costs when the principle is just about stationarity looking at the formulas

Answer (score 1):

If the mass $m<0$ is negative then OP's action functional would be manifestly $\leq 0$, and unbounded from below, i.e. it doesn't have a minimum.

Comment: I got your point, but I still don't fully understand: if the integral is definite and the lagrangian is a continue function, why $S$ shouldn't have a minimum?